# SQL Query to distance traveled in a day based on timestamp and lat long

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a table with Date and latitude, longitude values in each row. I want a sql query to calculate the distance travailed in a day.

Say for date `2013-03-01` I want the total distance traveled,

```
ID      DATE                  LAT     LONG    V_ID
---------------------------------------------------
123     2013-03-01 06:05:24   45.544  86.544   1
124     2013-03-01 06:15:17   45.676  86.676   1 
125     2013-03-01 06:25:24   46.544  86.544   2
126     2013-03-01 06:38:14   46.651  86.651   2
127     2013-03-02 07:12:04   46.876  86.876   1 
128     2013-03-02 10:38:14   46.871  86.871   1
129     2013-03-02 10:56:14   46.871  86.671   2
130     2013-03-02 15:28:02   46.243  86.871   2
```

To calculate the distance what I wrote a sql function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM](@lat1 FLOAT, @lat2 FLOAT, @lon1 FLOAT, @lon2 FLOAT)
 RETURNS FLOAT 
AS
BEGIN

RETURN ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0))*6371
END
```

but I want the total distance traveled in a day and for day `2013-03-01` I have top `four row` and I want total distance traveled in `2013-03-01`

and similar to this date `2013-03-02` has last four row , how do I calculate distance for these rows.

Comment: please remove the mysql tag or the sql-server tag. Can't be both

Comment: GROUP BY DATE and then SUM(dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(...))?

Comment: which version of sql server are you using? you may be able to use `STDistance` if you are using SQL Server 2008 +

Comment: Making use of LEAD too. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Comment: @ughai I am getting the distance with above mentioned query.. I am looking for query to get distance traveled in first four and last four rows (as  first four has one date and other has one)

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?. like Alex said you can use `LEAD` if you are using sql server 2012 or above

Comment: @ughai  I am using the 2008 version and trying the LEAD..thanks

Comment: it won't work on 2008, you'll have to do a self join and then use your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use self join with `ROW_NUMBER()` to get distance travelled like this.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae540/1)**

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT *,CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) as tday,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) ORDER BY [Date] ASC) rn
FROM Travel
)
    SELECT T1.tday,SUM([dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM](T1.lat,T2.lat,T1.long,T2.long)) as dist
    FROM CTE T1
    INNER JOIN CTE T2
        ON T1.tday = T2.tday
        AND T1.rn  = T2.rn -1
    GROUP BY T1.tday
```

**Output**

```
|       tday |               dist |
|------------|--------------------|
| 2013-03-01 | 129.40048639456964 |
| 2013-03-02 |  87.36216677343607 |
```

Comment: Thanks lot for this .. but i am getting error` Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An invalid floating point operation occurred.`

Comment: I have converted string values to float as `SELECT T1.tday,SUM([dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM]( CONVERT(float,T1.lat),CONVERT(float,T2.lat),CONVERT(float,T1.long),CONVERT(float,T2.long) )) as dist`

Comment: why is your lat and long `VARCHAR`? Might be a conversion issue but error seems to be something else.

Comment: every column is in varchar

Comment: check out  [bad habits to kick - choosing the wrong data type by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Hi If i need to query based on column `V_ID` 1 and 2 travelled on date 2013-03-01 and 2013-03-02 .. then what should i add

Comment: just add respective filters as `WHERE`

Comment: This works in fiddle with small data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98904d/1 but not with thousand of record.. one V_ID appears only for once (means for one date only)

Comment: If i understand your changes, you want to group distance based on `V_ID`s now, then add `V_ID`s in join condition, change the partition by to include `V_ID` as the first column and then add the respective date columns and add the `V_ID` in `group by`